# Ubuntu 22 problem with Openvpn client with tls handshake

Tags: kubuntu, vpn, openvpn

Hi there i have some problems with OpenVPN and ubuntu, i have ovpn file i should use but that not work because of tls check  **like below**

ovpn ::

```
client
proto udp
explicit-exit-notify
remote IP 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_ZUThkVPuS3bqOPcw name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
```

logs::

```
May 18 09:31:32 mohammed98 systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service for server.
May 18 09:31:37 mohammed98 systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service for server.
May 18 09:31:37 mohammed98 systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service for server...
May 18 09:31:37 mohammed98 openvpn[15477]: DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-256-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-256-CBC' to silence this warning.
May 18 09:31:37 mohammed98 openvpn[15477]: OpenVPN 2.5.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2022
May 18 09:31:37 mohammed98 systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service for server.
May 18 09:31:37 mohammed98 openvpn[15477]: NOTE: your local LAN uses the extremely common subnet address 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x.  Be aware that this might create routing conflicts if you connect to the VPN server from public locations such as internet cafes that use the same subnet.
May 19 10:19:58 mohammed98 NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1652948398.5930] vpn-connection[0x556bd2d98110,70144fd4-7a6f-4a77-8fc2-877799cbafcf,"mabdelawal3",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 1341378
May 19 10:19:58 mohammed98 NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1652948398.6371] vpn-connection[0x556bd2d98110,70144fd4-7a6f-4a77-8fc2-877799cbafcf,"mabdelawal3",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
May 19 10:19:58 mohammed98 NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1652948398.6372] vpn-connection[0x556bd2d98110,70144fd4-7a6f-4a77-8fc2-877799cbafcf,"mabdelawal3",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
May 19 10:19:58 mohammed98 nm-openvpn[1341382]: OpenVPN 2.5.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Mar 22 2022
May 19 10:20:58 mohammed98 NetworkManager[1090]: <warn>  [1652948458.4010] vpn-connection[0x556bd2d98110,70144fd4-7a6f-4a77-8fc2-877799cbafcf,"mabdelawal3",0]: VPN connection: connect timeout exceeded.
May 19 10:20:58 mohammed98 NetworkManager[1090]: <warn>  [1652948458.4063] vpn-connection[0x556bd2d98110,70144fd4-7a6f-4a77-8fc2-877799cbafcf,"mabdelawal3",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
May 19 10:20:58 mohammed98 NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1652948458.4063] vpn-connection[0x556bd2d98110,70144fd4-7a6f-4a77-8fc2-877799cbafcf,"mabdelawal3",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
May 19 10:20:58 mohammed98 NetworkManager[1090]: <info>  [1652948458.4064] vpn-connection[0x556bd2d98110,70144fd4-7a6f-4a77-8fc2-877799cbafcf,"mabdelawal3",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
```

I use KUbuntu 22.04, can any one help?